# Running a CMD command with Python, printing the output AND getting the output as variable

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command

I'm trying to build a script to automate the building process of a desktop application using pyinstaller. One of the things I need to achieve is running the pyinstaller command and getting the output of it as a string for further processing WHILE printing whatever the command is printing too to the Powershell window. Nowadays I'm just using os.system() but that doesn't return the output of the command as string, only the exit code.

I've tried with subproces.run() as demostrated in many other questions, but that doesn't return useful output to me, I run the command as

```
result = subprocess.run("pyinstaller app.py", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And trying

```
result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

To get the output of the command, but that returns nothing to me.

Answer (score 0):

With `subprocess.getoutput` it works on linux... hope it works for windows too

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.getoutput('pyinstaller app.py')
print(result)
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't print the command output to console. Doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Updated the example. Does it print now? :)